# Rselenium issue: browser opens and closes with an error

Tags: r, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

There is some issue with RSelenium. It shows the below error

```
rD <- rsDriver(port=4444L,browser="chrome")
remDr <- rD$client
```

The browser opens and closes with error

> Selenium message:unknown error: unable to discover open pages
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591
>   (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT
>   6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 60.76 seconds
>   Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
>   System info: host: 'HYD2-1860002767', ip: '10.54.67.19', os.name:
>   'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_131' Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
>
> Error:     Summary: UnknownError       Detail: An unknown server-side error
>   occurred while processing the command.     class:
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException     Further Details: run
>   errorDetails method

How to overcome this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have correctly added stand alone jar in your project. You can download it from official site of seleniumhq.
`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-x.xx.x.jar`

Should you have successfully added jar, try the code below:

`

```
public class Google {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","***location of your chromedriver.exe***");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

`

Comment: I'm not into programming, learning. Is this to be run in java(from cmd)?

Comment: Yes. This should be run in java. You can use IDE. Eclipse is best as if of now.